# Is there a way to transform this keylookup in an index scan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I'm not an SQL expert (I try to get jobs done - the faster the better, obviously), I don't know if the information I'm giving you is enough to solve the problem. I'm using SQL Server, SQL Management studio.

In this case I have a join query on the "a" table and the "o" table.

The two tables join on a column (let's say o.customer = a.customer) but they group on another column (o.opportunity) which is not present in the table a.

```
sum(case
when a.ActivityTypeCode=4202 and a.actualend>o.createdon
then 1
else 0 end)
as Feature_Name
```

This is the part of the query which creates a key lookup.

The seek predicate of the lookup says this:

```
Seek Keys[1]: Prefix: [MSCRMBauerMedia_MSCRM].[dbo].[ActivityPointerBase].ActivityId =
Scalar Operator([MSCRMBauerMedia_MSCRM].[dbo].[ActivityPointerBase].[ActivityId] as [a].[ActivityId])
```

I don't get what the predicate is telling me and how I can this be an index seek or index scan. I have indexes on all the variables involved in this query: on the single columns and covering indexes on all the variables.

Any idea or suggestion?

Thank you.

EDIT: This is the query. Attached there is the execution plan.

```
select tp0.* from
(
select
 o.opportunityid
,(sum(
case when a.ActivityTypeCode=4202 and a.actualend>o.createdon
then 1
else 0
end
))  as Phone_calls
,(sum(
case when a.ActivityTypeCode=4210 and a.actualend>o.createdon
then 1
else 0
end
))  as Emails
from OpportunityBase as o
left join ActivityPointerBase as a
on o.customerid = a.regardingobjectid
where o.actualclosedate is null and a.RegardingObjectTypeCode=1
group by 
o.opportunityid
 ) as tp0
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBA47.jpg

Comment: What problem are we trying to solve, exactly?  Poor performance?

Comment: What is it looking up (output columns)? Which Index is it seeking? And on which table? I think more of the query and more of the execution plan will be required to provide a decent answer.

Comment: I'm trying to solve a performance problem. Now I'm not on the PC, I'll post soon the whole query and the execution plan.

Comment: I added the remaining information: query and query plan.

Comment: How long does it take the query to run? How many rows in the two tables do you expect it to return? Does it matter if you use an inner join instead of a left join? And how's the ActivityPointerBase index called fndx_for_cas... (with the 7% cost) defined?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, looking at the query, the left join isn't required. Try an inner join instead.